# Tableau: Calculated Field based on Dimension and Measure

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm trying to set up a look at YoY based on quarters, thus (Q1 2016 Rev/Q2 2015 Rev) - 1.

My data is in quarters, so I'm trying to set up a calculated field with (Rev at Current Quarter / Rev at (Current Quarter - 4)) - 1

But I'm not sure how to set up that dependency in Tableau.

Thanks for reading

EDIT:

Example of Data

quarter_id  | quarter_revenue
10    |       200
11    |      430
12    |       250
13    |       300
14    |       405
15    |       493
16    |       299

So quarter_id 10 corresponds to 2015 Q1, then 11 is 2015 Q2, etc.  Currently I can set this into Tableau and use Quick Table Calculation: Percent Difference on Quarter_Revenue which gets me the difference for id 11 and 10 (2015 Q2 and 2015 Q1).

What I want to do is look a year ahead however, and do this calculation 4 quarters ahead.  So to compare 2015 Q1 vs 2016 Q1, I would need to do look at id 14 and id 10, and the calculation for Percent Difference would be (405/200)-1.

Comment: Can you share some sample data, screenshot or more information ? It's really hard to resolve/understand an issue with the given amount of text. Also read  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Good point Pirate, I've added context.

Comment: Achieving this might be possible with a couple of complex calculated fields but instead of teaching Tableau how to handle your data as quarters, is it not possible to put some real dates on the rows (such as 01.01.2015 for quarter_id). If not possible, maybe a calculated field to create this data could be made. When we have a date field, it will be very easy to make YoY visualizations.